# Efficient database design for a college notes application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I am designing a web application for storing different college material like notes, ebooks, question papers.

Requirements: 
1. Get list of Note based on branch and semester, like if "Computer Science Engineering" and semester 1 is selected then get all notes in that branch and semester.
2. Get all subjects based on semester and branch.

Terminology/What i have designed: 
A "Note" can be of type "Ebook", "Question Paper", "Practical File", "Note". Note will have a title, description and a file attachment. A note would belong to a subject and category.

Category: Like "Ebook", "Question Paper" etc. It will have a title.

Branch: It denotes the field of study like "Computer Science & Engineering", "Electrical Engineering" etc. It will have a title. A branch will have multiple semesters.

Subject: It will have a title. Like "Data Structures", "Machine Learning" etc.

Semester: Denotes the usual college semester. A semester will have multiple subjects. Different semesters can share subjects. Like a subject in 1st sem of Computer Science Engineering might be in 3rd sem of Electrical Engineering.

Below are the models I have currently made.

```rb
class Note < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :subject
end
```

```rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :notes
end
```

```rb
class Branch < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :semesters
end
```

```rb
class Semester < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects
  belongs_to :branch
end
```

```rb
class Subject < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :semesters
  has_many :notes
end
```

Schema File

```
create_table "branches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "short_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "notes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "subject_id"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_notes_on_category_id"
    t.index ["subject_id"], name: "index_notes_on_subject_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_notes_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "semesters", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "branch_id"
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "semester"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["branch_id"], name: "index_semesters_on_branch_id"
  end

  create_table "semesters_subjects", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "subject_id", null: false
    t.integer "semester_id", null: false
    t.index ["semester_id", "subject_id"], name: "index_semesters_subjects_on_semester_id_and_subject_id"
    t.index ["subject_id", "semester_id"], name: "index_semesters_subjects_on_subject_id_and_semester_id"
  end

  create_table "subjects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "short_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Currently I am getting subjects using branch and semester like this:

```rb
@subjects = Subject.joins(:semesters).where("semester_id = ? AND branch_id = ?", params[:semester], params[:branch]).pluck(:title, :id)
```

I feel this can be improved since I would be taking a join in all requests. What I want eventually is to create a filter UI with "Branch", "Semester" and "Subject" as selections to filter Notes.

Answer (score 0):

I think your design is fine, You can try with a scope_method which would ease filtering or even with class methods:

```
scope :branch_semester, -> {joins(:semesters).where("semester_id = ? AND 
     branch_id = ?", params[:semester], params[:branch]).pluck(:title, :id)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just fetch the `Branch` in this case

```rb
@subjects = Branch.find(params[:branch]).subjects
```

Branch and Semesters have a one-to-one so you don't need the subject id if you have the branch id. Notice that I'm asking `subjects` to `Branch`.

To do that just use `has_many :through`:

```rb
class Branch < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :semesters
  has_many :subjects, through: :semesters
end
```

I think your design is fine, it's standard relational database stuff. If you REALLY want to use joins, you can use some kind of metadata, like a JSON column in some table, but IMO that's an overkill in this case.

Premature optimization is the root of all evil. If you are caching you won't need to worry about that either.

Because your controller, instead of asking for `.subjects`, it can just return the branch:

```rb
@branch = Branch.find(params[:branch])
```

Then in your view

```rb
<% cache @branch do %>
  ... use @branch.subjects here, it will only be called once when generating the cache
<% end %>
```

Check out [Russian Doll Caching](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#russian-doll-caching) for more on this.